# What is cleos? Is it the main eos wallet like how bitcoin core is to bitcoin?

Tags: cleos, bitcoin

Is cleos the most trustworthy wallet like how bitcoin core software is to bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

No, `cleos` is not a wallet software; it's a CLI tool interfacing with nodes and wallet services.

EOSIO software is akin to Bitcoin Core, which comes with `bitcoind`, `bitcoin-qt`, and `bitcoin-cli`. These are comparable to `nodeos`, `keos`, and `cleos`, respectively. So, if you want to draw parallels with other blockchains, `cleos` is somewhat similar to `bitcoin-cli` in Bitcoin Core or with `geth` in Go Ethereum.

Perhaps the diagram below from [the documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/) may clear up how those tools interact with each other:

[image: Diagram from EOS Developer]

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the definitions of the two softwares.

From [eos developers guide](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/cleos-overview): cleos is a command line tool that interfaces with the REST API exposed by nodeos.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_Core) (the best description i can get): Bitcoin Core includes a transaction verification engine and connects to the bitcoin network as a full node.

From this description, bitcoin core can be seen as `cleos` + `nodeos` + `keosd`. Obviously `cleos` (aswell `keosd` and `nodeos`) is developed by block.one (eosio) so it should be reliable...